# does Entity Framework have a caching mechanism like DataSet/DataTables have?

Tags: entity-framework

does Entity Framework have a caching mechanism like DataSet/DataTables have?

In other words if you start using EF is it really just a way to easily get data in/out of the database without providing an additional caching layer like DataSet/DataTables did where you have an in-memory representation (on-line/off-line) and which at some point you could say to "persist all changes to database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how complex a cache you are referring to.

EF has an Object Cache.  See...

[Identity Resolution, State Management, and Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx)

> The ObjectContext  represents a container for in-memory objects. The object context, with the help of other classes and interfaces, manages an object's identity, state, original and current values of the object's properties, and tracks the changes made to each object in the cache.

and...

[Saving Changes and Managing Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx)

These articles introduce the EF Object Cache somewhat.

For further caching, you can write a wrapper as in...
http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/07/09/transparent-caching-support-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [caching provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) for entity framework. It contains 3 implementations of ICache interface which can be used in your applications:

- AspNetCache – cache which uses
  ASP.NET caching mechanism.
- InMemoryCache – simple, in-memory
  cache with basic LRU expiration
  policy.
- VelocityCache –
  implementation of caching which uses
  Microsoft Distributed Cache codename
  "Velocity" CTP3.